# JQuery Drop Down on Hover .slideDown and .slideUp Breaks in IE7 + 8

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, slidedown

My .hover function for my drop down menu's works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE9 + 10. However when I test them in IE7 + 8 they break. After searching the web for answers I've tried adding zoom: 1; to the drop menus in my CSS, because .slideUp/Down doesn't recognize position: relative; elements in IE7. Still have not found a fix for this...can someone please help?

JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.dropNavOne').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul.menu_body1').stop(true, true).slideDown(600);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul.menu_body1').stop(true, true).slideUp(600); 
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="dropNavOne" class="gradient">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">I am a...</a>
                <ul class="menu_body1">
                    <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Related CSS:

```
    .dropNavOne, .dropNavTwo {
float: left;
margin-top:10px;
padding-right: 5px;
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
    }

    .dropNavOne ul ul, .dropNavTwo ul ul {
display: none;
    }

    .dropNavOne ul, .dropNavTwo ul {
position: relative;
zoom: 1;
background: #bbbbbb;
padding: 0 5px; 
list-style: none;
display: inline-table;
margin: auto;
width: 190px;
opacity: 0.9;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
border-radius: 3px;
    }
.dropNavOne ul:after, .dropNavTwo ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

    .dropNavOne ul li, .dropNavTwo ul li {
position: relative;
zoom: 1;
width: 190px;
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }
.dropNavOne ul li:hover, .dropNavTwo ul li:hover {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #5e5e5e;
}

    .dropNavOne ul li:hover a, .dropNavTwo ul li:hover a {
        color: #c7c7c7;
    }

.dropNavOne ul li a, .dropNavTwo ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 5px;
    color: black; text-decoration: none;
}

    .dropNavOne ul ul, .dropNavTwo ul ul {
zoom: 1;
background: #5e5e5e; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
width: 275px;
opacity: 0.9;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    }
.dropNavOne ul ul li, .dropNavTwo ul ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid #6b6b6b;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #494949;
    width: 275px;
}
    .dropNavOne ul ul li a, .dropNavTwo ul ul li a {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #c7c7c7;
    }   
        .dropNavOne ul ul li a:hover, .dropNavTwo ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #333333;
        }
```

In IE7 the drop down's don't show at all, and in IE8 they are really buggy...in the right position but only show up partially and function (slide up/down) incorrectly.

Comment: What exactly does "they break" mean? are they not displaying in the right location? are they showing up behind where they are supposed to be? are they not showing at all? are you getting js errors? is the page blank?

Comment: Oh my apologies. In IE7 the drop down's don't show at all, and in IE8 they are really buggy...in the right position but only show up partially and function (slide up/down) incorrectly.